# Ng-cordova google analytics plugin does not work if active IDFA

Tags: cordova, mobile, google-analytics, cordova-plugins, idfa

I activated the IDFA parameter, and no longer work my analytics, and IDFA field is not recognized establishment of analytics. How is it possible ? my mistake implementation?

```
 window.ga.setAllowIDFACollection(true); 
 $cordovaGoogleAnalytics.setAllowIDFACollection(true); 
 $cordovaGoogleAnalytics.startTrackerWithId("MYCODE");
 $cordovaGoogleAnalytics.setAppVersion("2.4.1");
 $cordovaGoogleAnalytics.setUserId(userId || "NOT_LOGGED");
 analytics.trackView('welcom');
```

Ng-Cordova plugin : http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/googleAnalytics/

Versions:

```
iOS & Android
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 0.8.1 
Cordova : 6.3.1
Ionic : 1.7.14
```

Comment: Have you tried to contact the author of that third party plugin?  https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin

Comment: yes, i opened issue